# Download Excel File ASP VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel

My goal is to download the excel that I've created

The code so far and works properly :

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

        xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1) = "RECORD_STATUS"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 2) = "VENDOR_NO"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 3) = "PARTS_NO"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 4) = "EFECTIVE_DATE"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 5) = "CURRENCY_CODE"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(1, 6) = "PRICE"


        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 1) = "A"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 2) = "NSEA"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 3) = "13231JX02A"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 4) = "2013/03/03"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 5) = "IDR"
        xlWorkSheet.Cells(2, 6) = "10"

        xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\TemplateVendor.xlsx")

        xlWorkBook.Close()
        xlApp.Quit()
        releaseObject(xlApp)
        releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
```

This save in drive D, how could I save in the Desktop path and auto download the file, thanks

Comment: I must be a little confused as what your end goal is here? You create an excel file and then save it to drive: D. But you want to save it to the desktop and auto download the file? It seems to me, just provide the file on your server for whoever and let them download it from you, then they would pick where it goes...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)

xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(path & "TemplateVendor.xlsx")
```

about autodownload you can read [**here**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/bfarley/simple-web-file-download-in-vb-net/)

Comment: Can you provide the sample for the excel one so it can be popped up ?